# MSMQ + WCF - Retry with Growing Delay

Tags: wcf, message-queue, msmq, netmsmqbinding

I am using MSMQ 4 with WCF. We have a Microsoft Dynamics plugin putting a message on an queue. A service picks up the message and makes an HTTP request to another web server. The web server responds by putting another message on a different queue. A second service picks up the messages and sends the response back to Dynamics...

We have our retry queue set up to retry 3 times and then wait for 5 minutes before retrying again. The Dynamics system some times takes so long (due to other plugins) that we can round-trip before the database transaction commits. The user's aren't seeing the update come through for another 5 minutes.

I am curious if there is a way to configure the retry mechanism to retry incrementally. So, the first time it fails, it only waits a few seconds. If it fails a second time, it waits twice that. And the time between retries just keeps growing.

The problem with just reducing the time between retries is that a bad message could easily fill up a log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is no built-in way of doing this. One slightly involved option is to create multiple queues, each with its own retry/poison sub-queues, each with a growing retry delay. You can reuse the same handler for each queue - the only thing that changes is the configuration. You also need a handler that can read the poison sub-queues (`service`) and move the message to the next queue in the chain (`client`).

So, you set `receiveErrorHandling` to `Move`. The `maxRetryCycles` and `receiveRetryCount` are just `1`. Each queue will use a growing `retryCycleDelay`. Each queue you create will have a `poison` sub-queue created for it automatically. You simply read from each `poison` sub-queue and use a client to move it to the next queue.

I am sure someone could write some code that would automatically create N queues with a growing `retryCycleDelay` and hook it up all programmatically. Since it is the same handler/client for every queue, it wouldn't be a big deal.